# Abrir determinada tab ao clicar no link do navbar

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap, nav-bar, aba

Tenho uma navbar que possui varios links para mesma pagina que possui 3 tab. Preciso que ao clicar em um item da navbar ele abre a página com a tab específica selecionada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer assim (mas não funcionou):

```js
$("#menu").click(function(){
   $("#dados-capa").removeClass("active");
   $("#itens").addClass("active");
  })
```

PS. O sistema está em laravel, o link das tabs está nesse formato: /dados-capa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recriando a mesmo situação:

```js
$(document).on('click','.navbar-nav li a',function(){
  var tab = $(this).data('tab');
  $('.'+tab).trigger('click');
  console.log(tab);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tabs</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a class="active"  data-tab="tab1" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-tab="tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-tab="tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active tab1"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" class="tab2">Tab 2 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" class="tab3">Tab 3 2</a></li>
</ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    tab 1
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    tab 2
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    tab 3
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Veja que foi adicionado um `data-attr` com a tab ao `navbar` contendo qual nav das `tabs` deve ser clicado, após capturar o valor, trigera um `click` no navegador da `tab` com `classname` em questão.

OBS: `console.log()` está sobrando para você ver a tab indicada no exemplo, não é necessário no produto final.

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando o jQuery Tabs:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: #seutab });
```

Comment: Não estou usando Jquery Tabs, estou usando nav-tabs do bootstrap